# Angularjs How to Toggle div's in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, toggle, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working in angularjs and I need to toggle div in `ng-repeat` but its not working fine. jQuery click is also not working on this. On click of `pregroupMem()` anchor tag I am calling this function. and data id coming from this function and I am using this as `membersList` in `listdiv` div. I need to toggle this div on click of "custom-cn" anchor tag.There are multiple lists and in each of these lists there are there multiple `listdivs` . I need to toggle the particular div on the click of anchor tag of list.

```
This is my js to get all groups of members. 

 localStorageService.set('grpOpen', grps.openGroups);
 localStorageService.bind($scope, 'grpOpen');

    grs.init = init;
    function init()
    {
        getMyData();    
    }   
    $scope.data = null;

    DataService.getMyData().then(function successCallback(response) 
    {
        $scope.data = response.data.results;
        $scope.grpOpen.length = 0;
        $scope.grpOpen.push({'data': response.data.results});
    },function errorCallback(response) {

    });
```

This is js to get all members list of a group.I have updated this according to your

```
$scope.open = -1;
$scope.pregroupMem  = function(index,id,e){ 

        $rootScope.membersList = '';
        // $rootScope.membersList.length = 0;
        $scope.loading= true;

        DataService.getGrpMem(id).success(function (data) {
            $rootScope.membersList = data.results;
            $scope.data[index].shown = !$scope.data[index].shown;

            if( $scope.open >= 0 && $scope.data[$scope.open] ){
                $scope.data[$scope.open].shown = !$scope.data[$scope.open].shown;
            }
            if( $scope.open !== index ){
                $scope.data[index].shown = !$scope.data[index].shown;
            } 
            $scope.open = index;


        }).catch(function (err) {
              // Log error somehow.
        })
        .finally(function () {
          // Hide loading spinner whether our call succeeded or failed.
          $scope.loading = false;
        });

    }

<ul>
<li ng-repeat="groupsw in grpOpen[0].data track by $index"> 
  <a ng-click="pregroupMem($index,groupsw.grpId,$event)" class="custom-cn" href="javascript:;">{{ groupsw.grpName }}</a>

    <div class="listdiv"> 
        <ul class="userlist">
            <li ng-repeat="mymembers in membersList">
            <a class="add_user" href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></a>
            <div class="userlist">
            <span class="usnermalissval" ng-if="mymembers.Name != null">{{mymembers.Name}}</span>

            </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you include javascript code for it ?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to toggle here.  Can you clearly describe which HTML elements you are trying to show/hide?

Comment: There is anchor tag which has class "custom-cn". On click of this anchor tag i need to show hide div which has class "listdiv" after anchor tag.In this js function i want to add toggle script.

Comment: your comment here doesn't really clarify what you are trying to accomplish.  your anchor tag is calling an angular function that is loading data, it isn't toggling anything at all.  you should start off researching `ng-show`/`ng-hide`, and create another property to set `true/false` for use with one of them.

Comment: I have added javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in following way:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [
      {grpId: 1, grpName: 'One'},
      {grpId: 2, grpName: 'Two'},
      {grpId: 3, grpName: 'Three'},
      {grpId: 4, grpName: 'Four'},
      {grpId: 5, grpName: 'Five'}
    ]
    $scope.open = -1;
    $scope.pregroupMem = function(index, id, e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if( $scope.open >= 0 && $scope.data[$scope.open] ){
        $scope.data[$scope.open].shown = !$scope.data[$scope.open].shown;
      }
      if( $scope.open !== index ){
        $scope.data[index].shown = !$scope.data[index].shown;
      }
      $scope.open = index;
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <ul ng-controller="MyController">
    <li ng-repeat="groupsw in data">
      <a ng-click="pregroupMem($index, groupsw.grpId, $event)" class="custom-cn" href="javascript:;">{{ groupsw.grpName }}</a>

      <div class="listdiv" ng-show="groupsw.shown">
        <ul class="userlist">
          This is a child div of grpId: {{groupsw.grpId}}
        </ul>
      </div>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: my data is coming dynamically according to group ids.

Comment: Pour up you Ajax code in between my example. I had removed your code so that example can work.

Comment: I have changed my code according to your changes but it is showing $scope.data not found error.

Comment: I have added this but getting same error. $scope.data is undefined

Comment: Then there might be errors in hs code where you get all groups of members

Comment: Are they getting properly assigned to scope? Because for this method to work, both toggle function and the group list should be present on same scope.

Comment: Without looking at complete arrangement of controllers, it will take longer to help you.

Comment: Yes its working now but not proper way.When i click on same div then its working for all.but if i leave the first one open and click on second then it ramain open the two div.it should hide the first one and show on current clicked div.

Comment: That can be done with a flag value in scope, the index passed in method to open the divs, the flag value should be checked. If flag value is non negative, then the flagValue index should be set to false and new index should be shown along with setting flag value. Let me exemplify it in my code sample.

Comment: Div is not closing on click of group name.It's closing on click of any other group name.

Comment: fixed, added condition `if( $scope.open !== index ){`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125483/discussion-between-pankaj-and-web-dev).